# How to find arguments of a given equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, equation

I want to know for what values of x, *sinc(x)* function is going to be half of its max value. Notice that this question can be extended to a more general question such a way that we can not find inverse of a particular function easily, so we are forced to resort to simulation softwares like MATLAB to find the arguments by which equation can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

**1.- this does not solve the question**

```
syms x
eq= sinc(x)==0.5*max(sinc(x));
sol=solve(eq)
```

`sol=1` is a root, zero crossing, not half `max`.

2.- symbolic max doesn't work here either

```
syms x
assume(x,'real')
maxsinc=max(sinc(x))
```

again max return a trivial answer

**3.- Go numerical**

I know, symbolic operations look comfortable, but since it's mentioned that the objective is to generalise to **ANY function**, in my opinion numerical is far more useful, in the context of this question, than attempting just symbolic operations.

Working with numerical instead of symbolic one constrains the search to a known interval, with enough resolution (`dx` small enough) one can now easily find `max` for any value and for any analytical function.

**4.- Use function intersections**

i`ntersections.m` is not a standard MATLAB function, but it is public, free, and really robust as well as useful.

It was written by Douglas Schwarz and it is available [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections)

```
dx=.0001;
x=[-10:dx:10];
y1=sinc(x);

y2=sinc(x)-.5*max(y1);

x0=intersections([-10 10],[0 0],x,y2)
```

function intersections finds ALL half max roots, not just the first one coming from left side of the graph:

```
x0 =
   -0.6034
    0.6034
```

replace `sinc(x)` with any function and you will see how well `intersections` works.

Answer (score 1):

basically you just want to solve the equation sinc(x)=0.5*max(sinc(x))?
If so,

```
syms x
eq= sinc(x)==0.5*max(sinc(x));
sol=solve(eq);
```